# Gnome showing only single notification at once

Tags: gnome, notification

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and using Gnome DE (version 3.36) which is provided by default. I get many notifications from several apps, but I can see them individually, means the notifications pop up one at a time and I get the next one after I make some action on the notification such as closing it or simply clicking on it.

I was wondering if this is the intended behaviour on Gnome or my Gnome is broken. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304831/stack-multiple-libnotify-popups) post, but it doesn't seem to work. If it is the intended behaviour of Gnome, is there any way I can get the notification behaviour as KDE Plasma or Xfce where multiple notifications stack up?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?